# Business Central - modify query of built-in report

Tags: report, edit, dynamics-business-central

I have been tasked with figuring out how to add a date to a remittance advise report in Business Central.
Report number 400.
There is a posting date in BC and we want to add it to the report. The built-in report doesn't have this field. We have so many tables in there that I am not able to identify which table the report is pulling from.
Is there any way to determine which table it is pulling from so I can build it from scratch, or somehow extract the query from the report and modify it?

Comment: Please share the code you have tried with so far.

Comment: No code yet, still at the poke it and see what happens stage.